# SQL Server Multiple count dates subselect in same query

Tags: count, sql-server-2008-r2, orders, subquery

I'm trying to figure out a way to pull *Order Counts* per `customer id` as well as `date` of first and last order within a date range from an `Orders` table where each order has both a `buyer_id` and `seller_id`.  The Orders table contains `OrderNumber`, `Buyer_ID`, `Seller_ID`, `OpenDate`, `ClosedDate`.  I can run the following queries individually to achieve my goals, but I would like to have everything in the same query if possible.

Order_Table:

```
OrderNumber, Buyer_ID, Seller_ID, OpenDate, ClosedDate
```

Buyer_ID Orders:

```
select Buyer_ID, COUNT(*)as BuyerOrders
from
(
    select Buyer_ID
    from Orders
    where OpenDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
)
a
group by Buyer_ID
```

Seller_ID Orders:

```
select Seller_ID, COUNT(*)as SellerOrders
from
(
    select Seller_ID
    from Orders
    where OpenDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
)
a
group by Seller_ID
```

Dates of First and Last Order within that range: ??

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Since the result is a union and the same customer_id may have an entry as both buyer and seller, how can I put the information in the same row? My first attempt was to create a temporary table from the result of the Union, but I'm drawing a blank on how to display Buyer OrderCount, Seller OrderCount etc on the same row for each Customer_ID in the resulting table.

Comment: Thanks!  I may be pushing my luck here, but is there a way to pull in details of the customer from the customer table like name and include the actual order number?  Customer_Table: Customer_ID, Name, Email, Phone?

Comment: Since the result is a union and the same customer_id may have an entry as both buyer and seller, how can I put the information in the same row?  My first attempt was to create a temporary table from the result of the Union, but I'm drawing a blank on how to display Buyer OrderCount, Seller OrderCount etc on the same row for each Customer_ID in the resulting table.

Comment: My most sincere apologies to Skippy whose original answer was a very eloquent solution to my problem.  This is my first posting to this this forum and I wasn't sure how to handle enhancing the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 'Buyer' as Type, 
    Buyer_ID ID, 
    Count(*) OrderCount, 
    Min(OpenDate) FirstOrder, 
    Max(OpenDate) LastOrder
from Orders
where OpenDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
group by Buyer_ID

union

select 'Seller', 
    Seller_ID, 
    Count(*), 
    Min(OpenDate) FirstOrder, 
    Max(OpenDate) LastOrder
from Orders
where OpenDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
group by Seller_ID
```

[EDIT] Yes, a little bit of a cheek accepting my answer, then un-accepting it and changing the question! Anyway, try the following:

```
;with BuyerFirst (Buyer_ID, RowNum, BuyerCount, OrderID, OpenDate)
As
(select Buyer_ID, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Buyer_ID order by OpenDate, OrderID) as RowNum,
    count(*) over (partition by Buyer_ID) As BuyerCount, 
    OrderID, 
    OpenDate
from Orders
where OpenDate between @StartDate and @EndDate),

BuyerLast (Buyer_ID, RowNum, OrderID, OpenDate)
As
(select Buyer_ID, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Buyer_ID order by OpenDate Desc, OrderID Desc) as RowNum,
    OrderID, 
    OpenDate
from Orders
where OpenDate between @StartDate and @EndDate),

SellerFirst (Seller_ID, RowNum, SellerCount, OrderID, OpenDate)
As
(select Seller_ID, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Seller_ID order by OpenDate, OrderID) as RowNum,
    count(*) over (partition by Buyer_ID) As SellerCount, 
    OrderID, 
    OpenDate
from Orders
where OpenDate between @StartDate and @EndDate),

SellerLast (Seller_ID, RowNum, OrderID, OpenDate)
As
(select Seller_ID, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Seller_ID order by OpenDate Desc, OrderID Desc) as RowNum,
    OrderID, 
    OpenDate
from Orders
where OpenDate between @StartDate and @EndDate)


select c.*, 
    bf.BuyerCount, 
    bf.OpenDate As BuyerFirstOrderDate,
    bf.OrderID As BuyerFirstOrderID, 
    bl.OpenDate As BuyerLastOrderDate, 
    bl.OrderID As BuyerLastOrderID,
    sf.SellerCount, 
    sf.OpenDate As SellerFirstOrderDate,
    sf.OrderID As SellerFirstOrderID, 
    sl.OpenDate As SellerLastOrderDate, 
    sl.OrderID As SellerLastOrderID
from Customers c
    left join BuyerFirst bf on c.CustomerID = bf.Buyer_ID and bf.RowNum = 1
    left join SellerFirst sf on c.CustomerID = sf.Seller_ID and sf.RowNum = 1
    left join BuyerLast bl on c.CustomerID = bl.Buyer_ID and bl.RowNum = 1
    left join SellerLast sl on c.CustomerID = sl.Seller_ID and sl.RowNum = 1
```